# Not able to see Live Streaming channel in Azure Portal if created from .NET SDK Service Principal account

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I am not able to see Live Streaming channel in Azure Portal if created from .NET SDK Service Principal account. I am the Account Admin as well as "Owner" for the subscription as well as the same Media Service resource. If I create it from Portal I can see it. But, if created programmatically with SP account, not able to see it in Portal.

I have followed the sample from this link,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-live-tutorial-with-api

Thanks,

Avi

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample you linked to you are using the V3 API for Azure Media Services. Currently, you cannot use the Azure Portal to manage V3 resources. If you need a UX for managing V3 resources you can use the Azure Media Services Explorer for V3 which is available from github [here](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Media-Services-Explorer). We are working on updating the Azure Portal to support resources created with V3 API. The following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/migrate-from-v2-to-v3) provides details on differences between using v2 and v3 APIs. The Azure Portal only currently supports the v2 APIs.